# One to Many Schema Design in MongoDB: Can I avoid cross embedding and true linking?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql-aggregation

I am working on an e-commerc site for T-Shirts. There are 8 variations of T-Shirts, all of which are part of an "Edition" (or clothing line).
  I want to be able to always display all of the shirts which are a part of the edition, but be able to check if each one is in stock so that that can be indicated.

So right now I have two Schemas: A Shirt Schema, and an Edition Schema.  They are modeled (in mongoose) like so:

```
  ShirtSchema: {
    color: {
      type: String
    },
    size: {
      type: String
    },
    edition: {
      type: {} (This is where I would embed the entire edition schema)
    }
  }

  EditionSchema: {
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    dateCreated: {
      type: Date
    },
    members: {
      type: Array (This is where I would have to list one of every type of shirt)
    }
  }
```

So examples of the schemas would would be:

```
var newEdition = new editionSchema();
newEdition.name = 'newEdition';
newEdition.dateCreated = Date.now();
newEdition.members = [{
  // List one of every single shirt. I.E. Red, Blue etc. 
}];

// Insert these into the 'shirts' collection 10 times
var redShirt = new ShirtSchema();
redShirt.color = 'red';
redShirt.size = 'Large';
redShirt.edition = newEdition;
// Insert these into the 'shirts' collection 5 times
var redShirt = new ShirtSchema();
redShirt.color = 'red';
redShirt.size = 'Medium';
redShirt.edition = newEdition;

var blueShirt = new ShirtSchema();
blueShirt.color = 'blue';
blueShirt.size = 'Medium';
blueShirt.edition = newEdition;
```

I would like to be able to embed the edition right in the shirt objects, however I am not sure how I can do this.  If I embed the edition information in the ShirtSchema, then once all of the pants have been purchased (i.e. removed from the database) it seems I would not be able to retrieve the edition information.

However, right now it seems that the only way for me to check if there is a shirt of a certain type of color that is in stock is the following:

1. Retrieve the edition Schema.
2. Loop through all of the members (so that I know each of the members of the edition)
3. Loop through the entire shirts collection and check if at least one shirt in each of the colors exists

This seems like a lot of looping and I am wondering if there is an easier way?

Comment: Could explain the context around 1-3? If you want a shirt of a certain color, why can't you just check if there's a shirt of that color in the `shirts` collection?

Comment: If I have 5 red and 5 blue shirts originally, and then I sell all 5 red shirts, there will be no entries of red shirts (which is good).  The problem though, is that if I want to show all of the shirts that ever existed (so that I could show a "sold out" banner next to the red shirt (instead of it not just appear at all) I can't do that, because I won't have any of the data about the red shirt.